# Add custom fee to order Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to add custom fee to an order based on the Delivery and Collection Dates for the order.

I am using this plugin for Delivery and Collection dates http://ecommerce-team.com/delivery-date-and-comment.html

I think I can work in Observer.php of this plugin because I can see that dates are being received there.

I am new to magento development and don't know much about it; I tried to do this

```
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->setGrandTotal($amount);
```

this works and shows the total new amount there to user; But when order is placed it does not have new amount.

I also tried this. But it does not work.

```
    $order->getShippingAddress()->setGrandTotal(123);
    $order->setFeeAmount(12.1);
```

I also tried downloading and installing this module; but it does not work. I even tried to var_dump() something on this module but it did not show up on order page. That means this extensions is not working. I think if this module starts working then I can try to apply logic there. http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total

Comment: so what's your question ?

Comment: I either want to know why that 2nd module is not working; or How can I add additional fee using the Delivery Date and Comment Module.

Comment: you can create your module using [This Link](http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/#.UlIy2FOBLIU) with option 'Need Add New Order Total'.Please follow instruction to create order total module as describe in module creater.

Comment: check this link http://www.magikcommerce.com/magento-extra-fee-extension

Comment: @zaheer I am really loving the link you provided. i will try to create module when I am on pc.

Comment: @Zaheerabbas I have create module and installed it; it shows the amount but does not count it in grandtotal; Do you have any solution for this? :)

Comment: ok; now it started working :p

I was getting subtotals in the extension file using these lines which was somehow causing issue. 

$totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getTotals();
    $subtotal = $totals["subtotal"]->getValue();

Now I am using this


$subtotal=Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData()["subtotal"];


Now only issue left is that Tax amount is not being added in grand total. :(